# Hyperledger Explorer timeout: don't show transactions after 4 hours on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-explorer

I'm running a Hyperledger Fabric + Explorer application on Kubernetes. I'm able to create transactions and Hyperledger Explorer show them.

But after 4 hours and 30 minutes (on average), the Hyperledger Explorer don't update himself with new transactions and the logs are not very helpfull

> [ChannelEventHub.js]: _connect - timed out after:45000
>
> [Peer.js]: sendProposal - timed out after:45000

Any ideas where is the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Run syncstart.sh script so that it will sync the transaction details with your blockchain network.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I really want to understand why there is this bug. Sync the blockchain periodicaly is a solution but it can be complicated to implement in my infrastructure (I don't directly have access to the kubernetes cluster)

Comment: Where is syncstart.sh file, please reply me

Comment: Hey  @Vijay Here is the link: https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer/blob/main/syncstart.sh ,  Hyperledger Explorer has been moved to End of Life status

Comment: @adineshreddy1 thank you for replying. My issue was resolved by clearing the docker volumes and restarted. However as you said this Explorer moved to end then what will the next alternate for the explorer. Please could you reply me.